# Determining the conductor of an induced Dirichlet character

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, characters

Say I have a Dirichlet character $\chi$ mod $N$ and I know that $\chi$ is induced by a Dirichlet character $\chi'$ mod $M$ with $M|N$. I want to then say that the conductor of $\chi$ divides $M$, which intuitively seems to be the case. Does anyone know a simple proof (or disproof) of this?

For instance, it is not clear to me why $\chi$ can't also induced by a character mod $Q$ with $\gcd(M,Q)=1$.

Comment: A Dirichlet character is of the form $\chi(n)=\psi(n)1_{\gcd(n,N)=1}$ where $\psi$ is a $k$ periodic Dirichlet character and that $k$, the conductor of $\chi$, is minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Dirichlet character $\chi$ modulo $N$ is induced by a character $\chi'$ modulo $M$ exactly if it is constant on the residue classes modulo $M$ (see Lemma $17.20$ in [these lecture notes](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2015fa/LectureNotes17.pdf)). If it is constant on the residue classes modulo $M$ and $Q$, then it is also constant on the residue classes modulo $\gcd(M,Q)$, and thus it is also induced by a character modulo $\gcd(M,Q)$. It follows that the conductor of $\chi$ divides the modulus of every character that induces $\chi$, as otherwise their greatest common divisor would be less than the conductor and yet would be the modulus of a character that induces $\chi$.

Regarding your second paragraph, it follows from the above that $\gcd(M,Q)=1$ for $M$ and $Q$ moduli of characters that induce $\chi$ only if $\chi$ has conductor $1$, i.e. is a principal character.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.